# Flutter TabBar cut

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, tabs

I'm completely new to flutter and I'm trying to play with this app https://github.com/iamabhishek229313/tinder_clone for getting a better understanding of the language.

The code seems to be quite clean, at least it's easy to understand.

But I still have an issue, the tabbar is cutting the icons and I can’t figure why (nor how fix it):

[image]

I didn't edit the code at all yet, if my understanding is good the error seems to be in that file: https://github.com/iamabhishek229313/tinder_clone/blob/master/lib/HomePage.dart

Many Thanks !

**EDIT**: I just found the toolbarHeight property on the AppBar component, but it seems to be a fixed value, I don't feel this will fix the issue for every device.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the tab bar in title, instead you should use the tabBar in the bottom parameter of the appBar, that is where it should be You can modify your code like this, it will work.

```
 DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      bottom: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```